# Create a plot with dot and interpolation in R

Tags: r

This is my df:

```
            id power percent_power    relVO2   group
1  AC12-PRD-C1    25      21.73913  8.797619     CAD
2  AC12-PRD-C1    40      34.78261  9.758929     CAD
3  AC12-PRD-C1    55      47.82609 11.324405     CAD
4  AC12-PRD-C1    70      60.86957 12.800595     CAD
5  AC12-PRD-C1    85      73.91304 14.273810     CAD
6  AC12-PRD-C1   100      86.95652 16.020833     CAD
7  AC12-PRD-C1   115     100.00000 17.830357     CAD
8  AL13-PRD-C1    25      19.23077  7.733918     CAD
9  AL13-PRD-C1    40      30.76923  8.754386     CAD
10 AL13-PRD-C1    55      42.30769 10.000000     CAD
11 AL13-PRD-C1    70      53.84615 11.514620     CAD
12 AL13-PRD-C1    85      65.38462 13.444444     CAD
13 AL13-PRD-C1   100      76.92308 15.748538     CAD
14 AL13-PRD-C1   115      88.46154 16.970760     CAD
15 AL13-PRD-C1   130     100.00000 18.695906     CAD
16 BM06-PRD-S1    25      25.00000 10.094108 Healthy
17 BM06-PRD-S1    40      40.00000 11.734861 Healthy
18 BM06-PRD-S1    55      55.00000 14.120295 Healthy
19 BM06-PRD-S1    70      70.00000 16.133388 Healthy
20 BM06-PRD-S1    85      85.00000 18.494272 Healthy
21 BM06-PRD-S1   100     100.00000 20.654664 Healthy
22 CB19-PRD-S1    25      13.15789 12.621429 Healthy
23 CB19-PRD-S1    40      21.05263 13.510714 Healthy
24 CB19-PRD-S1    55      28.94737 15.446429 Healthy
25 CB19-PRD-S1    70      36.84211 17.771429 Healthy
26 CB19-PRD-S1    85      44.73684 18.639286 Healthy
27 CB19-PRD-S1   100      52.63158 21.050000 Healthy
28 CB19-PRD-S1   115      60.52632 23.985714 Healthy
29 CB19-PRD-S1   130      68.42105 25.582143 Healthy
30 CB19-PRD-S1   145      76.31579 28.000000 Healthy
31 CB19-PRD-S1   160      84.21053 29.150000 Healthy
32 CB19-PRD-S1   175      92.10526 33.489286 Healthy
33 CB19-PRD-S1   190     100.00000 34.907143 Healthy
34 CC14-PRD-S1    20      22.22222  9.634146 Healthy
35 CC14-PRD-S1    30      33.33333 10.747967 Healthy
36 CC14-PRD-S1    40      44.44444 12.089431 Healthy
37 CC14-PRD-S1    50      55.55556 14.288618 Healthy
38 CC14-PRD-S1    60      66.66667 15.341463 Healthy
39 CC14-PRD-S1    70      77.77778 16.207317 Healthy
40 CC14-PRD-S1    80      88.88889 18.117886 Healthy
41 CC14-PRD-S1    90     100.00000 19.556911 Healthy
42 DA03-PRD-C1    20      15.38462  8.047826     CAD
43 DA03-PRD-C1    30      23.07692  8.950000     CAD
44 DA03-PRD-C1    40      30.76923  9.710870     CAD
45 DA03-PRD-C1    50      38.46154 10.410870     CAD
46 DA03-PRD-C1    60      46.15385 10.850000     CAD
47 DA03-PRD-C1    70      53.84615 12.402174     CAD
48 DA03-PRD-C1    80      61.53846 13.410870     CAD
49 DA03-PRD-C1    90      69.23077 13.863043     CAD
50 DA03-PRD-C1   100      76.92308 14.754348     CAD
```

I would like to create a point plot for every `5%` on the x axis where the point are either connected or not.

What I have done at the moment is this `lm` regression.

```
dput %>% 
  filter(percent_power < 100) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = percent_power, y = relVO2, color = group)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = group, size = point_size, color = group)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2)) +
  xlab("Percentage of PPO (%)") + 
  ylab(expression(paste("V", O[2]," (mL/min/kg)"))) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(25, 100), breaks = seq(25, 100, by = 25)) +
  theme_classic()
```

Some participants don't have the 5% increment, so it has to be interpolated between the nearest lower value and the nearest higher value for each of them, and then get a mean value for every 5%.

This should look like this:

[image]

Thank you very much everyone,

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: In your comment below, you refer to some group, could you show it in your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the interpolated dataset first using `approx` within each `id`.  Then bind them together and plot:

To add the means I created an extra dataset of means with `dplyr`, then added `geom_line` and `geom_point` using this dataset.

```
interpolatedFrames <- by(dat ,  dat$id , FUN=function(d) 
  data.frame(relVO2=approx(d$percent_power, d$relVO2,xout = seq(25,100,5),rule = 1,)$y,
             percent_power=seq(25,100,5),
             id=d$id[1],
             group=d$group[1])
)
dat2 <- do.call(rbind, interpolatedFrames)

library(dplyr)
meanFrames <- dat2 |> group_by(percent_power, group) |> summarise(relVO2=mean(relVO2, na.rm=TRUE))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot( dat2 ) + 
  aes(x=percent_power,y=relVO2,shape=id) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_classic() + 
  xlab("Percentage of PPO (%)") + 
  ylab(expression(paste("V", O[2]," (mL/min/kg)"))) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(25, 100), breaks = seq(25, 100, by = 25)) +
  theme_classic() + 
  geom_line(data=meanFrames,aes(group=group,shape=NULL, lty=group))+ 
  geom_point(data=meanFrames,aes(group=group,shape=NULL, lty=group),shape=2)+
  labs(linetype="Group means", shape="Individual trajectories")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Then, how do you get the mean for each 5% to get a graph on the plot ?

Comment: what do you want exactly?  another line that is the mean average of the ids?

Comment: Yes, indeed, for each 5% value.

Comment: Thank you very much George. Is it possible to get two means (by group: `CAD` and `healthy`), with dots as well at each 5%?

Comment: George any help for the group stratification ? Thank you!

Comment: the group indicator is not in the dataset

Comment: oops, just updated the question. I would like to have 2 graphs (one for `CAD` and `healthy`, with dots at each 5% if possible, in addition to the line you already done. Thank you!

Comment: I've updated the answer.  Switched from stat_summary to making a new dataset to plot the means.  Not sure if it was necessary but it gives more control.  Note I stopped extrapolating the id with the missing values, because it probably biases the mean quite a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Since `approx` not really extrapolates, you could use `predict`ions over `nd` ("new data") of a GAM using `mgcv::gam`.

```
nd <- (0:20)/.2  ## use 5:20 to start percent_power at 25%
plot(relVO2 ~ percent_power, dat, type='n', xlim=range(nd), ylim=c(0, max(dat$relVO2)),
     xlab='PPO Score (%)', ylab=bquote('VO'[2]*'mL/kg/min'))
int <- by(dat, dat$id, \(x) {
  fit <- mgcv::gam(relVO2 ~ s(percent_power, k=nrow(x)), dat=x)
  aux <- data.frame(id=x$id[[1]], group=x$group[[1]], percent_power=nd,
                    relVO2=predict(fit, data.frame(percent_power=nd)), ext=2)  ## MARK
  aux$ext[aux$percent_power <= max(x$percent_power) & aux$percent_power >= min(x$percent_power)] <- 1
  points(relVO2 ~ percent_power, data=aux, pch=as.numeric(id), col=ext, cex=.8)
  invisible(aux)
}) |> do.call(what=rbind)

## get group means with `tapply`
mns <- with(int, tapply(relVO2, list(percent_power, group), mean))
lapply(seq_len(ncol(mns)), \(j) lines(rownames(mns), mns[, j], lty=j + 1)) |> invisible()

legend('topleft', pch=c(unique(dat$id), rep.int(NA, 2)), inset=.01,
       lty=c(rep.int(NA, length(unique(dat$id))), 2:3),
       legend=c(levels(dat$id), sprintf('mean group %s', unique(dat$group))), bty='n')
```

[image]

*Notes:* Change `nd` at will as noted in comment above. To not colorize extrapolations in red use `ext=1` (i.e. black color) at the `## MARK`.

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(id = c("AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", 
"AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", 
"AL13-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", 
"AL13-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", "BM06-PRD-S1", "BM06-PRD-S1", "BM06-PRD-S1", 
"BM06-PRD-S1", "BM06-PRD-S1", "BM06-PRD-S1", "CB19-PRD-S1", "CB19-PRD-S1", 
"CB19-PRD-S1", "CB19-PRD-S1", "CB19-PRD-S1", "CB19-PRD-S1", "CB19-PRD-S1", 
"CB19-PRD-S1", "CB19-PRD-S1", "CB19-PRD-S1", "CB19-PRD-S1", "CB19-PRD-S1", 
"CC14-PRD-S1", "CC14-PRD-S1", "CC14-PRD-S1", "CC14-PRD-S1", "CC14-PRD-S1", 
"CC14-PRD-S1", "CC14-PRD-S1", "CC14-PRD-S1", "DA03-PRD-C1", "DA03-PRD-C1", 
"DA03-PRD-C1", "DA03-PRD-C1", "DA03-PRD-C1", "DA03-PRD-C1", "DA03-PRD-C1", 
"DA03-PRD-C1", "DA03-PRD-C1"), power = c(25L, 40L, 55L, 70L, 
85L, 100L, 115L, 25L, 40L, 55L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 115L, 130L, 25L, 
40L, 55L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 25L, 40L, 55L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 115L, 
130L, 145L, 160L, 175L, 190L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 
90L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L, 100L), percent_power = c(21.73913, 
34.78261, 47.82609, 60.86957, 73.91304, 86.95652, 100, 19.23077, 
30.76923, 42.30769, 53.84615, 65.38462, 76.92308, 88.46154, 100, 
25, 40, 55, 70, 85, 100, 13.15789, 21.05263, 28.94737, 36.84211, 
44.73684, 52.63158, 60.52632, 68.42105, 76.31579, 84.21053, 92.10526, 
100, 22.22222, 33.33333, 44.44444, 55.55556, 66.66667, 77.77778, 
88.88889, 100, 15.38462, 23.07692, 30.76923, 38.46154, 46.15385, 
53.84615, 61.53846, 69.23077, 76.92308), relVO2 = c(8.797619, 
9.758929, 11.324405, 12.800595, 14.27381, 16.020833, 17.830357, 
7.733918, 8.754386, 10, 11.51462, 13.444444, 15.748538, 16.97076, 
18.695906, 10.094108, 11.734861, 14.120295, 16.133388, 18.494272, 
20.654664, 12.621429, 13.510714, 15.446429, 17.771429, 18.639286, 
21.05, 23.985714, 25.582143, 28, 29.15, 33.489286, 34.907143, 
9.634146, 10.747967, 12.089431, 14.288618, 15.341463, 16.207317, 
18.117886, 19.556911, 8.047826, 8.95, 9.71087, 10.41087, 10.85, 
12.402174, 13.41087, 13.863043, 14.754348)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "48", "49", "50"))

## transform id to factor (for pch) and invent a group that you didn't show
dat <- transform(dat, id=as.factor(id), group=substr(id, 10, 10))
```